# Badges on user pages are a bit off

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Would it be possible to nudge the class specifier for badges one pixel down?

In the current setting; the class of the badge (at least for bronze; the only kind of badges I have) is one pixel too far up, giving a rather unsightly badge look. (This concernsSafari/FireFox on Mac OS X, at least).

Current:

[image: current]

Better:

[image: better]

This off-by-one problem is, as far as I can tell, endemic.

Comment: Are they off by one pixel on everyone's user profile? And it's in the meta site right? Is it in the main site? I don't see in Chrome (8 beta). Have you made sure your font size is set to normal? (Ctrl+0) edit: I also don't see it in Firefox.

Comment: They are off by one pixel in Firefox for me, but not in Chrome or Opera. Using Ubuntu.

Comment: At least they're *readable* :) [Invisible Badges on Webmasters](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/354/white-text-on-badges-is-impossible-to-read)

Comment: Unbadgely, I'd say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The badge icon is indeed off by 1px on the full badge. I have put in a fix, should be in the next deployment.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [nudging your monitor one pixel up](http://www.sadtrombone.com/)?

---

On a more serious note, I don't see this issue:

[image: Chrome is perfect]
[image: Firefox is too]
(excuse my slightly outdated Firefox)

Comment: I will not excuse an outdated firefox!

Comment: Hehe, it's only outdated because it's obsoleted -- by Chrome.